# Feature Selection / Attribute Selection - Good overall performers

Tags: attributes, statistics, classification, feature-extraction, feature-selection

In the context of a large-scale data mining benchmarking study, I am comparing 15 algorithms over 9 data sets, leading to an overall 135 algorithm/dataset combinations. The study is done using WEKA.

My last analysis is concerned with the influence of **feature selection**. I am aware, that there is no such thing as the perfect feature selection algorithm but the optimal choice rather depends on both **algorithm to be deployed** and the **data set** to which it will be applied.

Although the problem is to large to find the optimal feature selection algorithm for each combination, I am looking for ones that are considered to show a good performance in general, 'allrounder' so to say. 
So far I have found recommendation for ***CFS*** (Correlation-based feature selection), ***ReliefF*** and ***Consistency***-based subset evaluation (Hall / Holmes 2002) as a generally good choice as well as the note from a survey, that methods as simple as ***Rankers*** (e.g. Correlation coefficient) proved quiet effective (Guyon / Ellissef 2003).

***Is there a good benchmark study some other research indicating which methods to use or which ones to use in practice?***

Comment: Can you provide more information about what type of classification problem are you trying to solve? Text classification, relational classification, ...?

Comment: The type of classification problems are all customer-centered problems, including e.g. risk classifications (bank or online transactions), direct marketing or high-percentage of return shipments in online shops. A priori probabilities of the economically relevant class vary greatly (from 5% to 50%) and total cost is used as evaluation criteria. Attribute types are mixed, including both nominals and numerics, where number of attributes ranges from 15-200 (depending on the coding of the attributes as well). AUC where total cost is inapplicable.

Comment: Algorithms include tradtional ones as C4.5, IBk, Logistic, NaiveBayes, CART but also SVMS and Metaclassifiers as Bagging, Boosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Text Classification point of view, there is one [article](http://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~ringger/Winter2007-CS601R-2/papers/yang97comparative.pdf) by Yang etal. comparing different feature selection algorithms (chi square, document frequency and Information Gain).

Although it is focus on text (i.e., the document frequency won't apply to you at all) the others might, depending on the nature of your features (i.e., binary or not, always present, ...)

I hope this helps.